# Fill matrix with For Loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I am trying to fill a matrix with a for loop in Python, this may be an math problem more than anything else, or I just need to find a new solution. I need to write this loop (just an example but the same concept):

```
matrix = np.zeros((1,8))
for i, j in zip(range(2,6), range(1,5)):
    matrix[0,0*i:2*i] = [i*2, j*2]
```

The expected output is the following:

```
[[4. 2. 6. 4. 8. 6. 10. 8.]]
```

That is, for the first iteration, column 0 and 1 of the matrix is filled, for the second iteration column 2 and is filled, etc.

For this I need the Loop for spit out the following matrixes:

```
matrix[0,0:2]
matrix[0,2:4]
matrix[0,4:6]
matrix[0,6:8]
```

The second part is easy, but how can I write a expression that first print out 0, to then print out 2, 4, 6 etc.

Thank you.

Comment: Your expected output is unclear. Could you edit your question to show the expected output?

Comment: This code raise `ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,) into shape (4,)`. Please explain the issue more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve this myself now, maybe not the most elegant solution, but it works. So instead of using the `range(2,6)` and `range(1,5)` to assign the values to the right place in the matrix, I added another variable `range(4)` which I call `p`.

```
matrix = np.zeros((1,8))
for i, j, p in zip(range(2,6), range(1,5), range(4)):
    matrix[0,2*p:2*p+2] = [i*2, j*2]
# Gives the output
print(matrix)
[[ 4.  2.  6.  4.  8.  6. 10.  8.]]
```